# ROS Answers SE migration: URDF model

Tags: gazebo, urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
I'm trying to build a urdf model of 2 legs attached with a joint (biped). the problem i am having is that the piece that attaches the two legs doesn't seem to be attached to them.
here is the urdf
and here[image: image description] is a picture of the problem

**edit1**: changed my urdf. now it doesn't jitter but nothing moves when I try controlling the joints in gazebo. i even deleted one foot and the model didn't fall over.
any idea what is wrong?

```
 <?xml version="1.0" ?>
<robot xmlns:sensor="http://playerstage.sourceforge.net/gazebo/xmlschema/#sensor"
       xmlns:controller="http://playerstage.sourceforge.net/gazebo/xmlschema/#controller"
       xmlns:interface="http://playerstage.sourceforge.net/gazebo/xmlschema/#interface"
       xmlns:xacro="http://playerstage.sourceforge.net/gazebo/xmlschema/#interface" name=
   "bip">
  




  <link name="R_leg">
   <inertial>
     <mass value="0.001"/>
       <origin xyz="0 0 0.5" rpy="0 0 0" />
     
     <inertia ixx="1.00"  ixy="0"  ixz="0" iyy="1.00" iyz="0"    izz="1.00" />
     </inertial>

   

   <visual>
     <origin xyz="0 0.2 0.5" rpy="0 0 0" />
     <geometry>
      <cylinder radius="0.02" length="1"/>
     </geometry>
   </visual>

   <collision>
     <origin xyz="0 0.2 0.5" rpy="0 0 0"/>
     <geometry>
       <cylinder radius="0.02" length="1"/>
     </geometry>
   </collision>
  
  </link>
  
  <link name="L_leg">
    <inertial>
     <mass value="0.001"/>
       <origin xyz="0 0 0.5" rpy="0 0 0" />
     
     <inertia ixx="1.00"  ixy="0"  ixz="0" iyy="1.00" iyz="0"    izz="1.00" />
     </inertial>

   

   <visual>
     <origin xyz="0 -0.20 0.5" rpy="0 0 0" />
     <geometry>
      <cylinder radius="0.02" length="1"/>
     </geometry>
   </visual>

   <collision>
     <origin xyz="0 -0.20 0.5" rpy="0 0 0"/>
     <geometry>
       <cylinder radius="0.02" length="1"/>
     </geometry>
   </collision>
  
  </link>
   <link name="C_mass"> 
    <inertial>
      <mass value="15.0" />
      <origin xyz="0 0.0 0" /> 
      <inertia  ixx="0.1" ixy="0.0"  ixz="0.0"  iyy="10"  iyz="0.0"  izz="0.1" />
    </inertial>

    <visual>
      <origin xyz="0 0 1" rpy="1.57 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <cylinder radius="0.02" length="0.5"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>

    <collision>
      <origin xyz="0 0 1" rpy="1.57 0 0" />
      <geometry>
         <cylinder radius="0.02" length="0.38"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>


   </link>

  

   <link name="R_foot"> 
      
    <inertial>
      <mass value="1.0" />
      <!-- center of mass (com) is defined w.r.t. link local   coordinate system -->
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" /> 
      <inertia  ixx="1.0" ixy="0.0"  ixz="0.0"  iyy="1.0"  iyz="0.0"  izz="1.0" />
    </inertial>

    <visual>
      <origin xyz="0 0.2 0.0005" rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.1 0.1 0.001"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    

    <collision>
      <origin xyz="0 0.2 0.0005" rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.1 0.1 0.001"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
   </link>

  <link name="L_foot"> 
      
    <inertial>
      <mass value="1.0" />
      <!-- center of mass (com) is defined w.r.t. link local   coordinate system -->
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" /> 
      <inertia  ixx="1.0" ixy="0.0"  ixz="0.0"  iyy="1.0"  iyz="0.0"  izz="1.0" />
    </inertial>

    <visual>
      <origin xyz="0 -0.2 0.0005" rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.1 0.1 0.001"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    

    <collision>
      <origin xyz="0 -0.20 0.0005" rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.1 0.1 0.001"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
   </link>-->

  <joint name="L_hip" type="revolute">
    <parent link="C_mass" />
     <child link="L_leg" />
     <origin xyz="0 -0.2 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
     <axis xyz="0 1 0"/>
  <limit upper="6.28" lower="-6.28" effort="1000" velocity="1000.00"/>
  <joint_properties damping="0.1" friction="0.80" />
  </joint>

 <joint name="R_hip" type="revolute">
   <parent link="C_mass" />
    <child link="R_leg" />
    <origin xyz="0 0.2 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
    <axis xyz="0 1 0"/>
     <limit upper="6.28" lower="-6.28" effort="1000" velocity="1000.00"/>
    <joint_properties damping="0.1" friction="0.80" />
  </joint>

  <joint name="L_ankle" type="revolute">
    <parent link="L_leg" />
     <child link="L_foot" />
     <origin xyz="0 0 -1" rpy="0 0 0" />
     <axis xyz="0 1 0"/>
       <limit upper="6.28" lower="-6.28" effort="1000" velocity="1000.00"/>
   <joint_properties damping="0.1" friction="0.05" />
  </joint>


  <joint name="R_ankle" type="revolute">
    <parent link="R_leg" />
     <child link="R_foot" />
     <origin xyz="0 0 -1" rpy="0 0 0" />
     <axis xyz="0 1 0"/>
   <limit upper="6.28" lower="-6.28" effort="1000" velocity="1000.00"/>
    <joint_properties damping="0.1" friction="0.05" />
  </joint>


<!--  -->


   
 <transmission type="SimpleTransmission" name="R_hip_trans">
  <actuator name="R_hip_motor" />
  <joint name="R_hip" />
  <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
</transmission>

<transmission type="SimpleTransmission" name="L_hip_trans">
  <actuator name="L_hip_motor" />
  <joint name="L_hip" />
  <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
</transmission>

<transmission type="SimpleTransmission" name="L_ankle_trans">
  <actuator name="L_ankle_motor" />
  <joint name="L_ankle" />
  <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
</transmission>

<transmission type="SimpleTransmission" name="R_ankle_trans">
  <actuator name="R_ankle_motor" />
  <joint name="R_ankle" />
  <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
</transmission>

 <!-- -->
 
<gazebo reference="C_mass">
    <turnGravityOff>false</turnGravityOff>
    <material>Gazebo/Blue</material>
  </gazebo>

  <gazebo reference="L_leg">
    <turnGravityOff>false</turnGravityOff>
    <material>Gazebo/Red</material>
  </gazebo>

<gazebo reference="R_leg">
    <turnGravityOff>false</turnGravityOff>
    <material>Gazebo/Red</material>
  </gazebo>

  <gazebo reference="R_foot">
    <turnGravityOff>true</turnGravityOff>
    <material>Gazebo/Yellow</material>
  </gazebo>

<gazebo reference="L_foot">
    <turnGravityOff>true</turnGravityOff>
    <material>Gazebo/Yellow</material>
  </gazebo>
<gazebo>
  <controller:BipController name="BipController" plugin="$(find pendelum_controller)/lib/libBipController.so">
    <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
    <update>100</update>    
    <updateRate>100.0</updateRate>
     <joint1>R_hip</joint1>
      <joint2>L_hip</joint2>
       <joint3>R_ankle</joint3>
        <joint4>L_ankle</joint4>
  </controller:BipController>
</gazebo>
 
  </robot>
```

Any ideas?
Thanks

Nachum

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46376/urdf-model/) by [Nachum](https://answers.ros.org/users/2980/nachum/) on ROS Answers with karma: 208 on 2012-10-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Running `check_urdf` (or rename your urdf to something.xml and open it with firefox) you'll see that there is an error with the `< limit` tag in the `R_hip` link:

```
rosrun urdf check_urdf answers-46376.urdf 
[ERROR] [1350837640.291120602]: Joint 'R_hip' is of type REVOLUTE but it does not specify limits
[ERROR] [1350837640.291120602]: joint xml is not initialized correctly
ERROR: Model Parsing the xml failed
```

fixing the malformed XML in the "R_hip" link by removing the space before `limit`:

```
     <limit upper="6.28" lower="-6.28" effort="1000" velocity="1000.00"/>
```

appears to fix the problem.

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2012-10-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nachum](https://answers.ros.org/users/2980/nachum/) on 2012-10-21**:
thanks. the space i already noticed and fixed. I would have thought that the model would fall to one side but it went crazy and broke to pieces. I did PD control on all the joints. it is better but still jittering some.

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2012-10-21**:
zero inertia's move infinitely fast with any finite force application :)

**Comment by [Nachum](https://answers.ros.org/users/2980/nachum/) on 2012-10-21**:
:) it looks likethat is part of the problem, but if yes two things are weird.the first that PD does control it it shouldn't if it is infinit, and secind why isn't it rotating around the upper joint?  i will check it tomorrow when i will get to work

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to specify the origin of the joint to be in the proper place relative to the parent link. For a rundown of how the origin tags work, check out [this geeky guy's presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g9WHxOpAUns&t=16m34s) on URDF (specifically the portion I linked to).

It may also help to use the joint_state_publisher and rviz to debug your model (as in the [URDF tutorials](http://ros.org/wiki/urdf/Tutorials/Building%20a%20Movable%20Robot%20Model%20with%20URDF). Using that approach is how I noticed that your legs did not rotate as I would expect them to.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2012-10-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nachum](https://answers.ros.org/users/2980/nachum/) on 2012-10-21**:
Thanks for the video. Great to see the face behind the name :)

**Comment by [Nachum](https://answers.ros.org/users/2980/nachum/) on 2012-10-21**:
i did change it to the place it should be in real world. still is braking as i wrote on the second answer/